# How do I restart an unresponsive Azure Web App (not responding in portal)

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I have two Azure Web Apps, that are not responding. They're on the same app service plan.

Normally I would restart them from portal, but that is not possible, it seems.

Advanced tools (kudu) are not working either - link does not work.

How can restart these apps?

[image]

Comment: i think you'd have to wait... once this issues are gone you can proceed to work with your webapp

Comment: @4c74356b41Wait for what?

Comment: for service disruption to end?

Comment: Ok, was not sure if you were referring to thebitguru's answer, or you had another idea.

Comment: i posted before he did, lol

Comment: After 18 hours of downtime the web apps came back online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, Azure is currently having issues in at least the south central US region.  I saw a tweet saying that the east region was also having issues.  If these issues are the cause of your app's unresponsiveness then you will have to first wait for Azure to resolve these issue.  For current status see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Comment: ..:This actually happens to be in South Central - down for 2+ hours. :(
Probably nothing I can do then. Thanks for the heads up.